# Error reading .xlsx file in ssis script task

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, xlsx

I have created a simple package wherein I take .xlsx file in 'Excel Source' task. Then, I read that file in next 'Script Task'. My script task in throwing the below error:

***"The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."***

The connection string that I am using in my script task is :

**l_strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                "Data Source=" + p_strFileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2\";";**.

I have used few other variations also but error is still coming. I also used :

**l_strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                "Data Source=" + p_strFileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";";**.

AND

**l_strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                "Data Source=" + p_strFileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";";**.

Please help. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Do you have the Access Database Engine installed? http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: There is no Jet 12 driver

Comment: Thanks @Peter_R. I will check for this and keep it in consideration.

Comment: @billinkc. I dont know what to say for your comment, but I have searched a lot where Jet12 is being used. Still searching for validating it.

Comment: @Abhi I must admit when I first saw it I read it as Ace driver not Jet, have you tried using the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` connection

Comment: Thanks @Peter_R. **Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0** worked for me :)